# PostgreSQL 9.6 stuck in recovery

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

There is a master server (9.6) and one replica. For over 1 year it has been working fine. We had to reconfigure CPU count on master and forgot to apply it on replica which effectively made it broken due to lack of archived pg_xlog files (we keep only small amount of it).  We tried to reinitialize replica (event with VM+PostgreSQL reinstall) as usual but we ended up with:

```
FATAL: the database system is starting up.
```

Verified configuration both on master and slave - looks fine. It was recovering consecutive segments, no stuck here. Free disk space is available both on master and slave. Unable to connect to the database thru `psql`.

`strace` on that process which recovers segments:

```
lseek(907, 0, SEEK_END)                 = 429228032
read(6, 0x7ffffb3dafc7, 1)              = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
lseek(3, 11747328, SEEK_SET)            = 11747328
read(3, "\223\320\1\0\2\0\0\0\0@\263\272V\25\0\0y\v\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\210\20\33\0008@["..., 8192) = 8192
read(6, 0x7ffffb3dafc7, 1)              = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
lseek(808, 0, SEEK_END)                 = 44916736
lseek(3, 11755520, SEEK_SET)            = 11755520
read(3, "\223\320\1\0\2\0\0\0\0`\263\272V\25\0\0\325\10\0\0\0\0\0\00025400041"..., 8192) = 8192
read(6, 0x7ffffb3dafc7, 1)              = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
lseek(840, 0, SEEK_END)                 = 860676096
read(6, 0x7ffffb3dafc7, 1)              = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
lseek(855, 0, SEEK_END)                 = 302235648
read(6, 0x7ffffb3dafc7, 1)              = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Thought of:

- permissions on recovery.conf (set to 600)
- PostgreSQL not reading postgresql.conf (unlikely)
- networking issue
- master corruption
- transactions on master blocking recovery on the slave

Any ideas?

Replica initialized with:

```
pg_basebackup -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data -P --xlog-method=stream -R --checkpoint=fast -U replica -W -h IP
```

pg_log just before it hit lack of pg_xlog files and started accepting connections:

```
< 2019-10-24 14:02:52.930 CEST > FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
< 2019-10-24 14:03:32.169 CEST > LOG:  shutting down
< 2019-10-24 14:03:57.270 CEST > LOG:  database system is shut down
< 2019-10-24 14:04:55.694 CEST > LOG:  00000: database system was shut down in recovery at 2019-10-24 14:03:57 CEST
< 2019-10-24 14:04:55.694 CEST > LOCATION:  StartupXLOG, xlog.c:6060
< 2019-10-24 14:04:55.694 CEST > LOG:  00000: entering standby mode
< 2019-10-24 14:04:55.694 CEST > LOCATION:  StartupXLOG, xlog.c:6135
< 2019-10-24 14:04:55.712 CEST > LOG:  00000: redo starts at 1553/E2012790
< 2019-10-24 14:04:55.712 CEST > LOCATION:  StartupXLOG, xlog.c:6833
< 2019-10-24 14:06:02.320 CEST > FATAL:  57P03: the database system is starting up
< 2019-10-24 14:06:02.320 CEST > LOCATION:  ProcessStartupPacket, postmaster.c:2221
< 2019-10-24 14:12:43.461 CEST > LOG:  00000: received fast shutdown request
< 2019-10-24 14:12:43.461 CEST > LOCATION:  pmdie, postmaster.c:2679
< 2019-10-24 14:14:17.410 CEST > LOG:  00000: shutting down
< 2019-10-24 14:14:17.410 CEST > LOCATION:  ShutdownXLOG, xlog.c:8095
< 2019-10-24 14:15:41.730 CEST > LOG:  00000: database system is shut down
< 2019-10-24 14:15:41.730 CEST > LOCATION:  UnlinkLockFiles, miscinit.c:763
< 2019-10-24 14:17:13.492 CEST > LOG:  00000: database system was shut down in recovery at 2019-10-24 14:15:40 CEST
< 2019-10-24 14:17:13.492 CEST > LOCATION:  StartupXLOG, xlog.c:6060
< 2019-10-24 14:17:13.553 CEST > LOG:  00000: entering standby mode
< 2019-10-24 14:17:13.553 CEST > LOCATION:  StartupXLOG, xlog.c:6135
< 2019-10-24 14:17:15.654 CEST > LOG:  00000: redo starts at 1555/C0019B8
< 2019-10-24 14:17:15.654 CEST > LOCATION:  StartupXLOG, xlog.c:6833
< 2019-10-24 14:17:29.507 CEST > FATAL:  57P03: the database system is starting up
< 2019-10-24 14:17:29.507 CEST > LOCATION:  ProcessStartupPacket, postmaster.c:2221
< 2019-10-24 14:29:46.171 CEST > LOG:  00000: consistent recovery state reached at 1557/5A30CB8
< 2019-10-24 14:29:46.171 CEST > LOCATION:  CheckRecoveryConsistency, xlog.c:7647
< 2019-10-24 14:29:46.171 CEST > LOG:  00000: database system is ready to accept read only connections
< 2019-10-24 14:29:46.171 CEST > LOCATION:  sigusr1_handler, postmaster.c:5023
< 2019-10-24 14:29:46.386 CEST > LOG:  00000: started streaming WAL from primary at 1557/6000000 on timeline 2
< 2019-10-24 14:29:46.386 CEST > LOCATION:  WalReceiverMain, walreceiver.c:384
```

Comment: To clarify, it's just the replica that's stuck in recovery?  What other errors do you see in the logs for the replica?

Comment: Yes, it's only the replica that it's stuck, just edited the question post adding logs from pg_log, I think there is noting more.

Comment: The last two lines seem to indicate that it's up and running and receiving WAL from the primary.  Is there still an issue?

Comment: @Jeremy: it's due to missing transaction log files, as we remove it on the master leaving them only for hours (we create backups other way). It started accepting connections, but it's not replicating. Once it was in recovery it forbids our connections thru psql. Might it be the case, that we should wait for hours , that it may somehow start accepting connections and replicate correctly?

Comment: Just tested on two separate VMs with exacly same configuration files as in our production case - works fine. So it might be related with either resources like storage or network, or even worse with the data itself :/

Comment: "pg_log just before it hit lack of pg_xlog files and started accepting connections"  If it  has started accepting connections, then what is the question?

Comment: @jjanes it started accepting connections but it is not replicating, it stopped at the time of initial backup, I think the only reason it started accepting connections is that it gone off the hot_stanby because of lack of pg_xlogs being deleted on the master due to the configuration. I hope that this clarifies everything. To recap: it is not replicating. We aim for: initial backup done, connect thru psql, see data replicating. We stopped at connecing, since it's not accepting connections, we see that message: "the database system is starting up.".

Comment: do you have any output from `pg_stat_replication`?  Maybe update the question with two snapshots of that view, to show that database is getting updated, but replication is not happening?

Comment: How are you monitoring the replication?  Are there log messages after the "started streaming WAL from primary" one?

Answer (score 0):

Finally we got it up and running. Here is what we did: moved unused data to the separate archive-like database server, did `vacuum full` on some big tables as well as `reindex` some multi-hundred gigabytes indices. We also modified `effective_io_concurrency` (increased) as it might have some impact due to our hybrid disk configuration (different on master and replica). Now instead of hours of waiting on replying logs, database starts accepting connections within a minute with replication working fine.